# Flutter How to make Stream complete before executing the next operation

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

The f method is a time-consuming operation, and it may be called in several places, and the time is not certain. I hope that the f method can be executed in the order of calling, and then execute the next time.

For example, A and B differ by 1 second to call the f method, and it takes 5 seconds to complete the execution of the f method. I hope that the f will be executed for the second time after 5 seconds.

code:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  StreamController<int> controller = StreamController();
  StreamSubscription streamSubscription =
      controller.stream.listen((event) async {
    await f(event);
  });

  controller.add(5);
  controller.add(3);
  controller.add(1);
}

Future<void> f(int duration) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration));
  print('$duration');
}
```

output:
1
3
5

the result i want: 5  3  1
How can I modify the code, or what other api to use

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your delay function and use the following:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  StreamController<int> controller = StreamController();
  StreamSubscription streamSubscription =
      controller.stream.listen(
  (event) => print('Event: $event'),
  onDone: () => print('Done'),
  onError: (error) => print(error),
);

  controller.add(5);
  controller.add(3);
  controller.add(1);
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use streams?

Why are you using streams if you want to ruin the point of using them.

```dart
void main() async {
  await f(5);
  await f(3);
  await f(1);
}

Future<void> f(int duration) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration));
  print('$duration');
}
```

output: 5 3 1 with delay 5s, 3s, 1s as you wanted